# Why is MySQLi stopping the rest of my page from parsing and stopping my PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to do some database stuff today and I've run into a bit of an issue when I realised that MySQLi keeps breaking my page. Allow me to explain. This is what I have on my server at [Exd.php](http://www.hausofalexander.tk/ExD.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ExD</title>
    <!-- Metadata -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Script begins here";
            $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '<Password>','ExD');
            if (!$link) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo 'Connected successfully';
            mysql_close($link);
            echo "Script ends here";
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I request this page from Chrome on my Mac, or even Chrome on the same machine serving this file, the only output on the page is from that first `echo` where I said the script began. If I look at the source of the page on the client this is what shows (**all** that shows):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ExD</title>
    <!-- Metadata -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Script begins here
```

ExD *is* a database which I've created in MySQL, and it contains one table which is named 'Person' with the columns of 'id' and 'name' (It's a basic table for debugging.)

Here is my PHP.ini file: [ExD PHP.ini on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uHUxRfbS)

I can also provide my phpinfo() if you really need it. Just a note -- I've looked at phpinfo() and all of the MySQL related cells (and MySQLi related cells) have values of the names of the people who have implemented them for PHP, so I'm guessing that means they work properly and they're enabled.

Why in the world is this happening? Why is MySQLi breaking the page?

**EDIT**: I've managed to make progress. Now I'm able to connect to the database and I'm given the 'Connected successfully' message on my page, but immediately after that is printed to the page it breaks again, so when I view the source in Chrome I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ExD</title>
    <!-- Metadata -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Script begins hereConnected successfully
```

So the page is still breaking but MySQLi is working until I call `mysql_close($link);`.

I've also made the following changes to PHP.ini:

`extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"`

`extension=php_mysqli.dll` (uncommented it)

You can visit my site again to see a demonstration! I'm a bit lost now as to exactly why this would happen.

**EDIT**: Thanks so much to rack_nilesh for noticing that I was calling the wrong extension methods! Everything is working as it should now. I'm so happy!

Comment: Check your error log files, or turn errors on?

Comment: My Apache error log says `Apache server interrupted...
able to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.` but if I look in PHP\etc\ I *do* see `php_mysqli.dll`.

Comment: I guess the mysqli module isn't installed on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `mysqli_connect`.

So `mysql_error` and `mysql_close` will be `mysqli_error` and  `mysqli_close` respectively.

Also confirm if password is correct and turn error reporting on.

Comment: Oh, gosh. Honestly I pasted this code from some other site when I was debugging. That was exactly what the issue was, aside from that weird automatically recommenting away the module load from the ext directory. I feel like an idiot now! Thank you so much for your sharp attention. Everything is working well now!

Answer (score 0):

I bet you don't have mysqli extension installed or enabled. Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Also do what @Naruto said.

Comment: I'm using 5.3.0+ so I'm being told that I shouldn't have to even worry about installing MySQLi. Nonetheless I've run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use `mysql` (not recommended) then change `mysqli_connect` to `mysql_connect`

Comment: Of course I'd much rather use mysqli. I don't even want to bother with mysql, I want to find out what's wrong and fix it! Thanks.